# Embed ustream audio feed to android app

Tags: android

Can someone help me with this? I have a Ustream channel that streams audio from my computer. It works perfectly using a web browser and the Ustream Android App, but what I want to do is to feed that stream to my own android application that i'm developing. Is there any way to make this possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

i know this is little late answer.

There is two way to do it.

- Ustream Embed Api: https://github.com/ustream/embedapi via WebView
- Ustream Player SDK: http://developers.ustream.tv/player-sdk.

Comment: Link for Ustream Player SDK is returning 404.

Anyone know where to get Android Player SDK now? Tried contacting their sales as the website says, but not getting any response.

Comment: Do I need an Enterprise account to be able to use Player SDK? I can't find the links for the SDK file and the link to get an Ustream API key. I only have the Pro trial account.